# how to get a variable from a link using jquery and php?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i have this script on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/patrioticcow/HysJ6/7/)

basically this links:

```
 | <a id="mine_click" href="#?test=123">test</a> | 
 | <a id="mine_click" href="#?test=123">test1</a> | 
 | <a id="mine_click" href="#?test=123">test2</a> | 
 | <a id="mine_click" href="#?test=123">test3</a> |
```

when i click on one of them i manage to change tabs but i want that `test` var to fallow and be displayed in the respective tab

any ideas?

Comment: Use `window.location.hash` to get the hash-part of your URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this function

```
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}
```

to get the variable and then print it.

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/HysJ6/10/

Comment: i test it, but it shows different values on different links. It doesn't keep the same vars, looks like you have to click 2 times on the link before the right result pops up